# For loops regression in R

Tags: r, for-loop, regression

I'm fitting GARCH model to the residuals of and ARIMA, and trying to apply ARCH(p) for p from 1 to 10 to compare the fitness. Here is my code. Errors are returned in the for loop part but I cannot figure out the reason why. Could anyone give some tips?

So for the single value p=1 the codes are as below and it's no problem.

```
fitone<- garchFit(~garch(1,0),data=logprice)
coef(fitone)
summary(fitone)
```

And for the for loop my codes go like

```
for (n in 1:10) {
  fit [[n]]<- garchFit(~garch(n,0),data=logprice)
  coef(fit[[n]])
  summary(fit[[n]])
} 

Error in .garchArgsParser(formula = formula, data = data, trace = FALSE) : 
  Formula and data units do not match.
```

I never wrote a loop code before. Can someone help me with the codes?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that generally one tries to evaluate all the variables in a formula in the context of the `data=` parameter, but your `n` variable isn't coming from `logprice`, it's coming from the global environment. You will need to dynamically create the formula. Here's one way to run all the models with `lapply` rather than a for look would be

```
library(fGarch)
#sample data
x.vec = as.vector(garchSim(garchSpec(rseed = 1985), n = 200)[,1])

fits <- lapply(1:10, function(n) {
    garchFit(bquote(~garch(.(n),0)), data = x.vec, trace = FALSE)       
})
```

and then we can get the coefs with

```
lapply(fits, coef)
```